# MFC CFileDialog - Getting special folder path on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, mfc, special-folders, cfiledialog

All.

I have some problem during writing an mfc application.
It is using the sample project, posted on below url, to implement multiple selection on CFileDialog.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/MFC/SelectDialog.aspx

It works fine on Windows Xp but has one problem on Windows 7.
The problem is that CFileDialog::GetFolderPath returns the empty string about the windows special folders such as Library/Documents on Windows 7.
So I tried like below.

```
if (FileDialog.DoModal() == IDOK) {
    tFolder = FileDialog.GetPathName();
}
```

This functions looks fine but It doesn't work when I select the folder on dialog.

Who can help me?

Waiting your answers... Regards.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the problem is that Win7 libraries do not have have a path in the file system (Actually, they are kind of an alias for a collection of paths).